# Eliminate flash of unstyled content in Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

Click any of the CodePen links on (for example) this page: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers

Notice the flash of unstyled content. How do you eliminate this?

I see it in my project when I do a hard refresh. I tried [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) but of course that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first hide the app

```html
<div id="app" hidden>...</div>
```

Then use `mounted.nextTick` to unhide the app once it is ready

```js
  new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    mounted:function(){this.$nextTick(function(){
      this.$el.removeAttribute('hidden')
    })}
  });
```